# In flowtype, how can you deal with types of callbacks in external modules?

Tags: flowtype, flow-typed

For example, in [pg](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed/blob/master/definitions/npm/pg_v6.x.x/test_pg_v6.x.x.js), there are callbacks that use an internal type `PG_Error`. This is not exposed via `modules.exports`.

So when I have to write a callback, say for

```
const c = new Pool(...);
c.connect((err: PG_Error, client: PoolClient, done: PoolConnectCallback) => ...);
```

How do I reference those types, which are not exported in the definition? At the moment I get errors like `Could not resolve name`.

I can copy these definitions out into a local definition file, but this doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 1):

If you do

```
import type {PG_ERROR, PoolClient ...} from 'pg';
```

That ought to make those names available in your namespace.